# Alternate of Windows Media Player in .NET 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-media-player

I have recently install Visual Studio 2022, And Select Windows Form Application .NET, and select .NET6 (long term support), Now When I want to add Windows Media Player in my project from COM Components, Its shows following:

```
 `The following controls were added but are not enable in the active designer. Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework`
```

Now What can I use here as alternate of Windows Media Player and why this error occurs in application?

Comment: .NET Core doesn't support ActiveX controls, which is what WMP is, so no, you can't use it. If you were using WPF you could use its `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I did not use WPF before, what developers use in .NET Core for Media Player? there should be alternative for this.

Comment: I don't think there's a lot of people out there in 2023 making _new_ WinForms applications with media playing functionality or porting their existing Framework apps to modern .NET. All the cool kids just send YouTube links now.

Comment: Ok. Is there is a way I can convert my project from modern .NET to .NET Framework? So I can use Windows Media Player?

Comment: If you've just started, it'd be simpler to just create a new .NET Framework 4.8 WinForms application in Visual Studio.

Comment: I agree more with Etienne de Martel's approach, rebuilding rather than converting.
According to my test, I opened the csproj file of a .net 6.0 Winforms project with Notepad, and changed <TargetFramework> to net472. Yes, this did change the target framework of the project to .net framework 4.7.2. But errors popped up one after another. There are too many non-common modules between .net framework and .net.